# D3 scale not mapping colors to values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a scale mapping integers to colors that determine the fill of a circle.

I have tried using d3.scaleThreshold to 'bucket' the values in the domain but to no avail. As it stands, the scale maps all the values to one color.

Would really appreciate any pointers here!

Code:

```
var colours = ["#6363FF", "#6373FF", "#63A3FF", "#63E3FF", "#63FFFB",
"#63FFCB","#63FF9B", "#63FF6B", "#7BFF63", "#BBFF63", "#DBFF63",           
"#FBFF63","#FFD363", "#FFB363", "#FF8363", "#FF7363", "#FF6364"];

var heatmapColour = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain(d3.range((0, 1, 1.0 / (colours.length - 1))))
.range(colours);

var hi_scale = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([0,100])
.domain(hi_extent);
```

Comment: Use an ordinal scale.

Comment: The range of domain values varies and are not sorted, so an ordinal scale would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a quantize scale

https://jsfiddle.net/erxws2c8/

```
var colours = ["#6363FF", "#6373FF", "#63A3FF", "#63E3FF", "#63FFFB",
"#63FFCB","#63FF9B", "#63FF6B", "#7BFF63", "#BBFF63", "#DBFF63",           
"#FBFF63","#FFD363", "#FFB363", "#FF8363", "#FF7363", "#FF6364"];

var heatmapColour = d3.scaleQuantize()
.domain(d3.range(0, 1, 1.0 / (colours.length - 1)))
.range(colours);
```

Also you had an extra set of parenthesis in `d3.range((0, 1, 1.0 / (colours.length - 1)))`, causing the function to see 1 argument instead of 3.

You may want to consider a quantile scale as well.

Comment: Ah this worked, really appreciate your help. Thank you!